# Can't find net.sourcefourge.jtds.jdbc.Driver in Tomcat web application

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, jtds

I'm learning how to deploy a web app with Tomcat and SQL Server. I'm using the jTDS driver to connect to MS SQL Server (jtds-1.3.1.jar), but I keep running into errors when I try to create a connection to the database. The program can't seem to find the jTDS driver classes. I know there's been several questions related to this on SE, but none of the solutions seem to work.

First, I'll describe how my project is set up. TOMCAT_HOME refers to the root directory of the Tomcat server. Here's a portion of my Tomcat directory:

```
TOMCAT_HOME\
    -lib\
         -jtds-1.3.1.jar
         -many other default jar files
    -webapps\
         -TestSite\
                -index.jsp
                -login.jsp
                -WEB-INF\
                       -classes\
                             -com\
                                   -testsite\
                                        -LoginServlet.class
                                        -ConnectionManager.class
                                        -UserDAO.class
                                        -UserBean.class
                       -lib\
                       -web.xml
```

The package for the class files are `com.testsite`, hence the subdirectories within the `classes` folder. Reading the Tomcat documentation, placing jar files in the root `lib` folder will allow all web apps to access them. (I've also tried putting the jar files in the `webapps\TestSite\WEB-INF\lib\` directory, but get the same error).

In my web application, I'm registering the jTDS with the DriverManager in one of my classes, which is called from a servlet.:

```
package com.testsite;
import java.sql.*;

public class ConnectionManager {
    static Connection con;
    static String url;

    public static Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
         url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/testdb";
         Class.forName("net.sourcefourge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");

         con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"username","password");
         return con;
    }
 }
```

When I start up the Tomcat server, I'm able to successfully navigate to the starting page, but when I try to login (which calls the `getConnection()` method), it gives the following error. Why can it not see it in the `lib\` folder? How can I fix it?

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourcefourge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClas
sLoaderBase.java:1305)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClas
sLoaderBase.java:1157)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at com.trainingsite.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.ja
va:22)
```

Comment: That should be OK. Make sure you restart the container after copying the JAR file into `/lib`. Can you share your project in [GitHub](https://github.com/), for instance? Additionally, you should really move `url` into `getConnection()`, remove `con` and return it directly; whenever you are using it further should be the responsible for closing it.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the error was due to a hard-to-see typo. I originally misspelled `sourceforge`:

```
Class.forName("net.sourcefourge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
```

It should be:

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
```

Another common typo, apparently, is mixing up `jdbc` and `jbdc` in the name.

Everything works as expected after fixing that.